# Model perform badly on test data

Tags: classification, anomaly-detection

I am working on a anaomaly detection/classification problem.
I trained a model HistGradientBoostingClassifier in sklearn.
The dataset is imbalanced, so I used f1 score as the metric to validate the model performance.
The model seems to perform well during the fitting process with GridSearchCV, and it performed well too on the test set. 
[image: The model seems to perform well during the fitting process]

However, when I tested it with new dataset, the model performance is very bad
[image: the model performance is very bad]

So I have a few questions:

1. In the first image, you can see train loss is much less than the validation loss. Is this an indication of overfitting ?
2. If it is overfitting, why does it perform well on the test data(f1 score is about 0.9) ?
3. Why does it perform so bad on new data ? (f1 score is about 0.06 in the 2nd image)
4. What should be my next step to tackle this problem ?

Comment: How are the 2015 and 2016 datasets different from the original?

Comment: Is the task Anomaly Detection? Because that is somewhat different than classification - in particular the behavior on novel anomalies. https://www.flair-tech.com/en/why-anomaly-detection-is-not-binary-classification/

Answer (score 0):

i think you must try **SMOTE** or **SMOTETomek** on your train data before fitting .

**SMOTE** and **SMOTETomek** algorithms available in imbalanced-learn : [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html#smote)

Comment: What would this solve?

Comment: smote algorithm increase number of low population data and dataset will be balanced

Comment: tomek algorithm reduce number of high population data and again dataset will be balanced . and make your learning better . at the end tomek alone does not give good result

Comment: But the performance was good on test set, indicating that this is not an imbalance problem? Instead, I suspect that it is an out-of-distribution / generalization problem. Which SMOTE or variants cannot be expected to help with, in general